# Using JavaScript to retrieve more than one value from HTML element?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a PHP script in which I need to pass three values to a select box's value, for example:

```
echo  '<option value="' . $city . "," . $row['start_date'] . "," . $row['end_date'] . '">' . $row['start_date'] . " - " . $row['end_date'] . '</option>';
```

Looks like this in HTML:

```
<option value="la,10/19/2019,10/20/2019">10/19/2019 - 10/20/2019</option>
```

So I need to receive the city, start date, and end date from the value. How do I get all three values from that box using JavaScript and separate them into their own unique variables?

If I am using the wrong terminology here, please edit the post to reflect the correct terminology.

Comment: The `value` attribute can have only one (string) value. If you want to encode more than one conceptual value in that string, you'll have to take it apart with your own code. Exactly how you do that depends on how you clump the values together.

Comment: assuming you have the code to retrieve the value already, you would simply do
`const items = value.split(','); `
`return { city: items[0], startDate: items[1], endDate: items[2] }`

Comment: I am not sure if I understand your question so I answered in a client side scope. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the value by querying the dom with something like this:

```
const value = document.querySelector('option').value;
```

And you can use `split()` to separate the string into an array of three strings:

```
const optionValues = value.split(',');
const city = optionValues[0];
const startDate = optionValues[1];
const endDate = optionValues[2];
```

Comment: How do I define them all separately then?

Comment: `arrayOfValues` will be something like0 `['la','10/19/2019','10/20/2019']`, so you can acces the city with `arrayOfValues[0]`, the start date with `arrayOfvalues[1]` and end date with `arrayOfValues[2]`

Comment: Or what I would probably do: `const city = arrayOfValues[0]; const startDate = arrayOfValues[1]; const endDate = arrayOfValues[2];`

Answer (score 0):

you could use `.split()`

```
const Sel = document.getElementById("city");
const val = Sel.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
const.pts = val.split(',');

console.log(pts)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `split` function and split it by `,`.

```
const arr = val.split(",");
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand clearly what you are asking for.

It seems you are rendering an `html` `<form>` using a `PHP` **templated view**.

I assume you want to programmatically, client-side, want to use `Ecmascript 6` (aka JavaScript) to manipulate your `entities`.

You can structure an `Entity` `class`, and update it anywhere using your `<select>`, for example, this all the cycle you need to know about:

```js
class Entity {
  constructor(city, startDate, endDate) {
    this.city = city;
    this.startDate = new Date(startDate);
    this.endDate = new Date(endDate);
  }
  
  toString() {
    return `In ${this.city} between ${this.startDate} and ${this.endDate}`;
  }
}

function bindEvents() {
  const form = document.querySelector('form[name="example"]');
  
  form.addEventListener('submit', onSubmit, true);
  form.picker.addEventListener('change', onChangePicker, true);
}

function onChangePicker(e) {
  const [city, startDate, endDate] = e.target.value.split(',');
  const entity = new Entity(city, startDate, endDate);
  updateResult(entity);
}

function updateResult(description) {
  document.querySelector('form[name="example"] span[name="result"]')
    .innerHTML = description;
}

// imagine you want to submit
async function onSubmit(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  const select = document.querySelector('select[name="picker"]')
  const [city, startDate, endDate] = select[select.selectedIndex].value.split(',');
  const entity = new Entity(city, startDate, endDate);
  entity.updateDate = new Date().toISOString();
  const response = await fetch('https://httpbin.org/post', {
    method: 'POST',
    headers: {
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(entity),
  });
  // this is an example and totally depend on your server
  const content = await response.json();
  console.log(content.data);
}


window.onload = bindEvents;
```

```css
span[name="result"] {
  color: #652484;
}

label {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<form name="example">
  <label for="picker">Selected value: <span name="result"></span></label>
  <select name="picker">
    <option value="Los Angeles,10/19/2019,10/20/2019">10/19/2019 - 10/20/2019</option>
    <option value="New York,11/19/2019,11/20/2019">11/19/2019 - 11/20/2019</option>
    <option value="Chicago,12/19/2019,12/20/2019">12/19/2019 - 12/20/2019</option>
  </select>
  <div>
    <button name="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

This is for modern browsers (`Chrome`, `Safari`, `IE11`, `Firefox`).

I hope it help.

Answer (score 0):

```
[city,from,to]= document.querySelector('option').value.split(',');
```

In a real situation you would if course get the value from the select element and not from the option contained therein.